# Family of functions $e^{-x^n}$

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, exponential-function

I am interested in the family of functions

$$f(n,x)=e^{-x^n}$$

of which we get the scaled normal distribution $f(2,x)=e^{-x^2}$.

It's an interest I have as a research project for a group of high-paced learners to work on and realized that I have never really seen these functions ever before in my studies save the example above and of course $f(1,x)$.  I was hoping to gain some possible references or sites that might lead me in the direction of what they are called and where they might found / applied.

Comment: You might want to look at the [generalised gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_gamma_distribution) when $d=1$

Comment: That was awesome.  A quick check shows it's related to the Weibull Distribution as well.  This is exactly the kind of info I was into.  If anyone else still has other information I'd be happy too, but this seems like a great start (and maybe game-set-match)!  Thanks @Henry

Answer (score 2):

[Weibull distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) are the most obvious case at first glance of some of the common distributions from my textbook ([link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZf5Z.jpg)). They have pdf

$$f(x;\lambda,k) = \frac{k}{\lambda^k} x^{k-1}e^{-(x/\lambda)^{k}} $$

As it happens,

$$e^{-x^n} = \frac 1 n \cdot f(x;1,n)$$

---

They can fall into a class known as [generalized Gaussians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_normal_distribution) among several other names (generalized normal, generalized error, exponential power).

Version $1$ on Wikipedia is what you might want. We consider a random variable in the parameters $\mu,\alpha,\beta$ where $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ is our mean and $\alpha,\beta > 0$, and the pdf of the random variable is

$$f(x;\mu,\alpha,\beta) = \frac{\beta}{2\alpha\Gamma(1/\beta)} \; 
                          e^{-(|x-\mu|/\alpha)^\beta}$$

The function of the type you discuss satisfies

$$e^{-x^n} = \frac{2 \cdot \Gamma(1/n)}{n} \cdot f(x;0,\alpha,n)$$

for positive $x$.

---

Another example as brought up in the comments is the case for [generalized gamma distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_gamma_distribution). In this case we have parameters $a,d,p > 0$ and pdf

$$f(x; a, d, p) = \frac{(p /a^d) x^{d-1} e^{-(x/a)^p}}{\Gamma(d/p)}$$

In this case,

$$e^{-x^n} = \frac{\Gamma(1/n)}{n} \cdot f(x;1,1,n)$$